# mutate_if, summarize_at etc coerce data.table to data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tibble

It seems like some `dplyr` functions, including `mutate_if`, `mutate_all`, `mutate_at` etc coerce data.table inputs to data.frame. That seems like strange behaviour, even though it is documented in `?mutate_all` (Under 'Value', it says 'data.frame' - but it does not coerce tibbles to data.frames.)

```
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
data("iris")
dt <- as.data.table(iris)
class(dt)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

```
class(mutate_if(dt, is.numeric, as.numeric))
#[1] "data.frame"
```

However, this does not happen with tibbles:

```
tb <- as_tibble(iris)
class(tb)
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

```
class(mutate_if(tb, is.numeric, as.numeric))
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Is there some way to maintain the data.table, or do i need to coerce with `as.data.table` every time I use one of the scoped `mutate` functions?

Comment: According to the documentation, dplyr functions try to return the same type of object as the input. Since `data.table` is not a base class, it returns `data.frame`

Comment: tbl_df is not a base class either.

Comment: dplyr is meant to work with tibbles.

Comment: I've never tested this, but perhaps check [this package](https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr)

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg. The dtplyr package seems to need a little bit of tender, loving care - i tried installing it and retrying my reprex, but all I get are errors. I actually thought data.table as a backend was built into dplyr.

Comment: dplyr and data.table are like oil and water. I don't think they will be ever able to integrate properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to try an alternative,
I recently released the [`table.express`](https://asardaes.github.io/table.express/articles/table.express.html) package,
which uses many `dplyr` and custom verbs to build `data.table` expressions.

The linked vignette provides detailed explanations,
but some examples:

```
library(data.table)
library(table.express)

data("iris")
DT <- as.data.table(iris)

# mutate_all (modification by reference does not print)
DT %>%
  mutate_sd(everything(), as.integer)

# mutate_if
DT %>%
  mutate_sd(~ is.numeric(.x), as.integer)

# mutate_at
DT %>%
  mutate_sd(contains("."), ~ .x * 1.5)

# transmute_all
DT %>%
  transmute_sd(everything(), as.integer)

# transmute_if
DT %>%
  transmute_sd(~ is.numeric(.x), as.integer)

# transmute_at
DT %>%
  transmute_sd(contains("."), as.integer)
```

Do note that `mutate_sd` modifies by reference by default,
so re-define `DT` between examples if you like.

Also, as of version 0.3.0,
you won't be able to load both `table.express` and `dtplyr` at the same time,
since they define the same `data.table` methods for many `dplyr` generics.

Comment: This appears to be the dogs b*llocks. I like the syntax, and it has a benifit of combining a dplyr like syntax with some transparency that you are using data.table as backend.

Answer (score 1):

There may be no *satisfying* answer to your question, but these wrapper functions would make it such that you wouldn't have to convert back to a data table every time.

And if you didn't want to include these in each script or project, and you didn't want to put them in your `.Rprofile`, you could even make an itty-bitty package out of them. It's surprisingly easy.

```r
mutate_all <- function(.tbl, ...) {
  if ("data.table" %in% class(.tbl)) {
    .tbl %>% mutate_all(...) %>% as.data.table()
  } else {
    .tbl %>% mutate_all(...)
  }
}
mutate_if <- function(.tbl, ...) {
  if ("data.table" %in% class(.tbl)) {
    .tbl %>% mutate_if(...) %>% as.data.table()
  } else {
    .tbl %>% mutate_if(...)
  }
}
mutate_at <- function(.tbl, ...) {
  if ("data.table" %in% class(.tbl)) {
    .tbl %>% mutate_at(...) %>% as.data.table()
  } else {
    .tbl %>% mutate_at(...)
  }
}
transmute_all <- function(.tbl, ...) {
  if ("data.table" %in% class(.tbl)) {
    .tbl %>% transmute_all(...) %>% as.data.table()
  } else {
    .tbl %>% transmute_all(...)
  }
}
transmute_if <- function(.tbl, ...) {
  if ("data.table" %in% class(.tbl)) {
    .tbl %>% transmute_if(...) %>% as.data.table()
  } else {
    .tbl %>% transmute_if(...)
  }
}
transmute_at <- function(.tbl, ...) {
  if ("data.table" %in% class(.tbl)) {
    .tbl %>% transmute_at(...) %>% as.data.table()
  } else {
    .tbl %>% transmute_at(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way to go. I've decided, for now, to do the same thing by defining new methods for mutate etc like this: 
mutate.data.table <- function (.data, ...) {as.data.table(mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...))}
which is basically the dplyr:::mutate.data.frame method with as.data.frame replaced by as.data.table. Still quite unsatisfactory, though.

Comment: @BjaRule do you consider this the accepted answer? just tying up loose ends.

Comment: I upvoted because think this is a decent workaround, but doesn’t actually solve the issue. If dtplyr worked, that would be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
df %>%
mutate_if(yourmutate) %>%
data.table()
```

Your frame will be both `data.table` and `data.frame`.

Following your example:

```
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
data("iris")
dt <- as.data.table(iris)
class(dt)
#
dt <- mutate_if(dt, is.numeric, as.numeric) %>% data.table()
class(dt)
```